# Error "Expression expected", what expression am I missing?

Tags: java, android

I am really new to Android Studio and programming and I have an error come up saying but I don't know what I've missed. I've put the code down below.

```
findViewById(R.id.myButton).bringToFront(View);
//view is where it is saying Expression expected
```

Comment: Off-top: Code *snippets* are meant to be used with code which can be run via browser (HTML/JavaScript/CSS). If you want to post only text of your code with proper formatting use `code block` (`{}` icon in editors menu).

Comment: View is an object.  It needs to be defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
findViewById(R.id.myButton).bringToFront();
```

should work for you.